# Display a value in HTML using MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list held by Session's variable. Suppose: `Session["SOF"]`.
Within this list, there are several items. Suppose each item is an integer. Let's say I want to find the item which has the value `9` and then display the item's value in HTML (this thing is clearly stupid but it is just example).

Here is what I tried in my HTML code in order to display the number:

```
@(List<int>(Session["SOF"]).FirstOrDefault(x => x.value == 9).ToString());
```

obviously it didn't work. So how can I do it?

Comment: `suppose`/`let's say` <= lot of assumptions or is this what you actually have? Also try not to use Session unless you really can't find a way not to. MVC (and also asp.net) should ideally be stateless. Chances are there is a better way to pass data for whatever it is you are trying to do. Also this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `foreach` in this case

Try this:

```
@foreach(var item in Session["SOF"])
{
    if(item == 9)
    {
        <span>@item.ToString()</span>
    }
}
```

Maybe casting to a `List<int>` will be needed for Session["SOF"], but give it a try.